# Is there special PvP armor?

Tags: destiny

I want to buy Destiny, although I'm only interested in PvP actually. 
So I'd like to know if there is something like special PvP armor, like stuff you only unlock for playing PvP and that only gives you bonus stats which are useful for PvP. Or can everyone just play with his equipment farmed in PvE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your armor and other gear transfers between PvP and PvE freely.  Certain stats are flattened in general PvP play for balance.

There is however special gear that can only be bought by gaining Crucible Marks and Reputation.  You gain these by participating in Crucible matches which is just the in-game name for PvP.  You can buy then spend them at a special Crucible vendor in the tower.

**So yes, there is armor that is exclusively gained through PvP play.**

Answer (score 1):

The gear can either be found from loot in PvE or as mission rewards in both PvP and PvE. This includes armour, weapons, and class-specific gear.